# Rails app works on one heroku app but not the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I currently have my Rails app deployed on one heroku app and everything works fine.

I also have another version deployed on another heroku app.

When I try to deploy my updated code on the second app I get the error:

Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

Here are the logs where I am getting an error. Sorry for the screen grab, no copy/paste.

[image]

EDIT: The app also works perfectly on local

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have having traffic which is more than current heroku dynos can handle. Increase that up, may be that will solve the problem. To find the exact problem use newrelic, it shows the `request queuing` time. If that time is big enough you should consider adding more dynos. The timeout also occurs when we have long running process in controller action. Use `rake-timeout` gem so if that process crosses the peak waiting time, you should get `Rake::Timeout` which you can rescue it somewhere and determines its backtraces.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, even if there is no traffic on the site?

Comment: consider restarting it. May be you have long running task in action and visited multiple times in that route.